# Sync My Timesheets to QuickBooks in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have an rails application, where employees are creating their weekly time sheets, now i want to upload those weekly time sheets on quick books using my rails app.

How can i do this in ROR ?

Thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an account on https://developer.intuit.com
2. Create an app and sandbox after logging in.
3. Hook up Rails to talk to the sandbox.
4. See [my](http://minimul.com/connect-rails-and-quickbooks-online-via-a-sandbox.html) [tutorials](http://minimul.com/integrating-rails-and-quickbooks-online-via-the-version-3-api-part-1.html) to help with these 3 steps.
5. TimeActivity is supported by the [quickbooks-ruby
   gem](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby) so check the [docs](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/timeactivity) and [specs](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/blob/master/spec/lib/quickbooks/model/time_activity_spec.rb) for implementation.
6. You will need to implement the Employee or Vendor entity as that reference is required to sync TimeActivity.
7. When ready for production enable this within your app at https://developer.intuit.com and then follow steps similar to 1-3 to configure.

Comment: As per your gem https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/blob/master/lib/quickbooks/model/time_activity.rb here, how would i send multiple timesheets row in one go to quickbooks ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have already implemented these steps. But how can i send my approved timesheet on Quickbooks ? Which method of TimeActivity Model  i need to use for sending timesheet ?

Comment: Click on the "specs" link in my answer that should give you a good idea how to map your data against the TimeActivity entity.